# How can I run the demo of viso2_ros for monocular odometry?

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, viso2-ros, libviso2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I'm working with ROS and libviso. Could anyone tell me the steps that I have to follow in order to get the odometry? The file demo.launch is specially for stereo vision? It could be easily edited in order to use it just with one camera?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/89176/how-can-i-run-the-demo-of-viso2_ros-for-monocular-odometry?/) by [Ellian Herrera](https://answers.ros.org/users/5491/ellian-herrera/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-10-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Ellian!

I've just added two [launchfiles](https://github.com/srv/viso2/tree/groovy/viso2_ros/launch) in the groovy branch, one for mono and the other for stereo. Both have all the parameters listed with the default values.

Enjoy!

---

Originally posted by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) with karma: 1471 on 2013-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3